# No pictures under "Manage Accounts" in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, user-accounts

I have a new Windows 7 64-bit computer.The first time I ran it, I created an administrator account. Later on, I realized that it would be a good idea to have this account be a standard account and have another account as an administrator account. I created a new administrator account, changed my current account type to standard, logged out, and logged back in. Both accounts are now password protected. Now, whenever I do soemthing that requries admin access, it asks me for the password to the admin account. When I go to "Manage Accounts" under "User Accounts" in Control Panel (I provide the admin account password), I cannot see the pictures for the two accounts. However, I do see the picture for the Guest account, which is disabled. How can I get these pictures to show?

I don't like anything wrong on my computer, so thanks if you can help!

Comment: Can you go into these accounts and change the picture to another picture? I'm thinking this might be a permissions issue and if you set the pictures for the accounts from the Admin account, they should show. It is still weird though.

Comment: Yes, I can do everything with these accounts that I would be able to do were I logged in with the admin account. Going to "Change the picture" does what it should, and I can see all the pictures that can be used. However, even after changing the picture, I still see a white box for that account.

Comment: I think this question needs a Bounty, you are not alone, no answers so far..http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en/w7itproui/thread/97bf1419-f4da-40ac-a206-0e6517182eb6..  http://forums.techarena.in/windows-software/1358204.htm

Comment: Yes, I've seen those. I have yet to try Clean Boot, but I don't think it is worth it. I don't have enough reputation to put a Bounty on this question. I don't really think there is a solution; I'll just have to wait for Microsoft to fix it.